# mongodb query embedded doc key as date

Tags: java, mongodb

Here is my mongodb document with embedded documents. The "events" is a list of documents (BasicDBList) in which each document is stored with key as some date (e.g. Jan 1, 2013) and value is a bunch of fields. The structure is defined this way so I can get all events happened on some date (e.g. Jan 1, 2013).

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to structure this document? I am not sure key
   as a date is a good idea but at the same time I want to
   retrieve all documents easily and store them in memory based on date. When
   I retrieve documents, I want a Hashtable with key as date and value
   as a List of documents for that date (using Java).
2. How do I retrieve documents by passing a date? For example, I want
   all the documents with key as Jan 1, 2013. What would be the query
   in Java?

```
{  
  "_id": {  
    "_time": 1367928493,  
    "_machine": -1914548796,  
    "_inc": -1784811303,  
    "_new": false  
  },  
  "email": "xyz@yahoo.com",  
  "events": {  
    "Jan 1, 2013": [  
      {  
        "desc": "My Desc",  
        "title": "My Title",  
        "createDateTime": "May 7, 2013 8:08:13 AM",  
        "updateDateTime": "May 7, 2013 8:08:13 AM"  
      },  
      {  
        "desc": "My Desc2",  
        "title": "My Title2",  
        "createDateTime": "May 7, 2013 8:08:13 AM",
        "updateDateTime": "May 7, 2013 8:08:13 AM"
      }
    ],
    "Feb 1, 2013": [
      {
        "desc": "My Desc3",
        "title": "My Title3",
        "createDateTime": "May 8, 2013 8:08:13 AM",
        "updateDateTime": "May 7, 2013 8:08:13 AM"
      },
      {
        "desc": "My Desc3",
        "title": "My Title3",
        "createDateTime": "May 8, 2013 8:08:13 AM",
        "updateDateTime": "May 8, 2013 8:08:13 AM"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you querying for particular date on a specific document or across all documents?

Comment: I have two requirements: 1) Retrieve all documents for all dates 2) Retrieve all documents for a particular date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you are not allowed to query by a json key, but you can use this trick:

```
db.things.find( { key : { $exists : true } } );
```

this query is to find the document which has a specific key

However, I believe this is not the best approach to solve your prolem. First, the events object of the document seems will  grow unpredictably in the future, this is  what we should avoid in designing the schema, because as the document grows, mongodb has to relocate the disk space to store it, which will cause performance problem.

I recommend to store the events object in a seperate collection, the 'owner' and 'date' fields are what you will query by.

```
{ 
  "owner":"xyz@yahoo.com",
  "date":"Jan 1, 2013",
  "events":[  
    {  
       "desc": "My Desc",  
       "title": "My Title",  
       "createDateTime": "May 7, 2013 8:08:13 AM",  
       "updateDateTime": "May 7, 2013 8:08:13 AM"  
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When I used find $exists : true as mentioned in your comment, I was getting all the events for all dates for the document structure I have in my question. But regardless of that, I really like your suggestion for schema. It is simplified and makes sense. Thank you so much.