# Query nested object based on key in MongoDB

Tags: performance, mongodb

My Schema Sample:

```
 {
   _id: '1234',
    daily: {
        '12-06-03':{
                  a:1,
                  b:2
         },
         '12-06-04':{
                  c:1,
                  d:2
         },
         '12-06-05':{
                  e:1,
                  f:2
         },
         '12-06-06':{
                  a:1,
                  b:2
         }
     }
 }
```

My Query: i want to query All 'daily' object's nested objects greater than or less than particular date (assume: 12-06-05).

I understand one method is to retrieve entire daily object and then compare by iterating over each key of daily object.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do what you are asking. Can't you model your documents in a different way, for example {_id:'1234', daily : [{date: '12-06-03', data: {a:1, b:2}}, {date: '12-06-04', data : {c:1, d:2}}....]} ?  If you model it that way, it becomes a simple query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mongodb query embedded doc key as date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450671/mongodb-query-embedded-doc-key-as-date)

Comment: Thanks, Mzzl and WiredPrairie. But i am aware of this and  want to avoid object's array.